# User defined function ```R``` fails to run

Tags: r, function, matrix

I would to learn to how to create function in `R` for simulating data based on the original data. I have access to toy data from (which is confidential) and I am not allowed to share. At the same time, data is to big to share.

1. Data is similar as below but I reduced the size substantially.

```
epsilon=2 
rs=matrix(rnorm(n=10000),nrow=10000, ncol=100) 
ival=matrix(rnorm(n=10, mean=50, sd=30), nrow=10, ncol=100) 
r1= matrix(c(5.5,5.7, 5, 6, 6.5, 7, 6.8, 7.4,8,10), nrow=10, ncol=1) 
r2= matrix(c(6.5,7, 6.5, 8, 10, 13, 13, 15,18,20), nrow=10, ncol=1)
```

2. Based on above data, now I would like to simulate to generate new data. Therefore, I created following function to do so. But it doesn't seem to run well. Your suggestions and help will be highly appreciated

```
toyfunction = function(epsilon, rs, ival, r1, r2 ){
  toydata=matrix(0, nrow=10000,ncol=100)
  r=matrix(0,nrow=10,ncol=100)
  r[1:10,]=5
  
  for(i in 1:1000){
    for(col in 1:100){
      #1-5 rows
      for(row in 1:5){
        toydata[row+(i-1)*10,col]=ival[row, col]+rs[row+(i-1)*10,col]
      }
      #6-10 rows
      for(row in 6:10){
        toydata[row+(i-1)*10,col]=toydata[row-5+(i-1)*10,col] + epsilon*log(r[row-1,1]/r[row-10,1]) + rs[row+(i-1)*10,col]
        
        if(toydata[row+(i-1)*10,col] < 45){
          r[row,col]=r1[row,1]
        }
        else{
          r[row,col]=r2[row,1]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

mydata=toyfunction(epsilon,rs, ival,r1, r2)
```

I will be highly grateful for your help and suggestions. I am also assuming that function will give me output in matrix. This is also crucial for me as I will have to do some matrix algebra later for the analysis.

Comment: It would be easier answering  if an explanation about how you would like to generate the data is provided.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: My expected output is a data stored in matrix. Have I understood your question correctly @Ben G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am new here, so I cant add any comments to your question.

Your problem here is this guy:

`epsilon*log(r[row-1,1]/r[row-10,1])`

This is a vector (try: i = 1, row = 6, col = 1); so you get a vector on the right hand side trying to replace a zero on the matrix.

Comment: Also, you might want define what's returned from your function at the end: `return(toydata)`

Comment: return(toydata) resolved the issue. Retrospective, I feel so stupid of myself. By the way, many thanks for the help. Also thank you ALL for your time and suggestions. Best.

Comment: Cool! Glad to be of help. Take care!